# Remove value from end of list based on distance of next value in list

Tags: python, terminal

I have a list consisting of a lot of numbers which has been sorted smallest to largest.

```
syslist[1,2,...,2690, 2691, 2692, 2693, 6000, 6699, 7000, 8000, 9000, 9001, 9900]
```

As you can see this is an example of the list and majority of the numbers go in a numerical sequence, with a few outliers at the end of the list. What Is a check in place in a for loop, that starts at the end of the list which is 9900. If the distance between that number 9900 to 9001 is greater then 1. it will pop 9900 out of the list. now 9001 is the end number of the list. Next the code iterates through and finds that 9000 is 1 less then 9001, a second check needs to take place within to see if the distance is greater then one in this case it is. So this will pop both 9001 and 9000 from the list. The expected out come is that 2693 is at the end of the list.

```
===>[1,2,...,2690, 2691, 2692, 2693]
```

One thing to note I didn't want to hard code these outlier value in an exclusion list.

If you can help me find a solution to this it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to check from the end of the list? Can't you rather check from the beginning of the list and find the first outlier - you remove everything after that. This would satisfy the requirements that you have described. For example:

```
def check_outliers(array):
    for i in range(0,len(array)-1):
        if array[i] +1 != array[i+1]: # Find the first outlier
            return array[:i+1] #Discard everything after that
    return array #Otherwise there are no outliers and we return the array as it is
```

**Edit after the comment**

if for that precise scenario you know that all the data until `2693` is acceptable, regardless of the gaps there. You can add a check:

```
def check_outliers(array):
    for i in range(0,len(array)-1):
        if array[i] >= 2693:
            if array[i] +1 != array[i+1]: # Find the first outlier
                return array[:i+1] #Discard everything after that
    return array
```

Comment: Hey, the reason it needs to start at the end of list is so I can add the next numerical value in the sequence. In the file that we have there are missing number early in the file, however these are not to be worried about. Which is why I want to start at the end of the list to pop out these value. Would the code above do that? Thanks too :)

Comment: It is not deterministic which values are to be ignored and which values are to be overwritten. If your question is about this exact sequence, just put a check in between if you have already reached the desired value. So let's say you know that until `2693` all your data is acceptable. You could do something like this:
Add this as a third line in the snippet:

`if array[i] >= 2693:`